# Im having trouble with using a custom navigation bar in SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6

Im making an app that has a login screen and when I log in my custom navigation bar works fine and has the proper image but after i close the app and reopen the navigation bar is the default white color. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "navbar_bg") 
[UINavigationBar .appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, forBarMetrics:.Default)]
```

Comment: show your code for navigation bar.

Comment: let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "navbar_bg")

[UINavigationBar .appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, forBarMetrics:.Default)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to set image for navigation bar:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "navbar_bg")

self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image,forBarMetrics: .Default)
```